# Xcode Objective-C SKNode property is null after instantiation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, null, sknode

Matrix.h code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Matrix : NSObject
+(id)matrix;
@property SKNode *window;
@end
```

Matrix.m code:

```
#import "Matrix.h"

@implementation Matrix

+(id)matrix
{
    Matrix *matrix;
    matrix.window = [SKNode node];

    if(matrix.window == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"matrix.window is NULL");
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

The code above is for an object Matrix. In the constructor it instantiates a SKNode property and then uses an if-statement to check if it is null.

After instantiating a Matrix object the debug log is:

```
2015-02-27 20:11:51.597
test[4165:415758] matrix.window is NULL
```

When the code runs the if statement is always triggered. Can someone explain why the matrix.window is NULL even though I have instantiated it?

Comment: `matrix` was not allocated... You should instanciate one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the code:  Matrix *matrix; to: Matrix *matrix = [Matrix alloc];

Comment: Don't forget to call `init`, the idiom to create an instance is `[[Class alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix` is not being allocated or instantiated:

```
Matrix *matrix;

// change to

Matrix *matrix = [[Matrix alloc] init];
```